# Firebird. Sql. Как реализовать поиск по следующему условию

Tags: sql, firebird

Есть таблица,в которой хранятся данные о сотрудниках, датах их приема на работу и дате увольнения. Но есть такие,которые были уволены и снова приняты. Так вот как вывести именно этих сотрудников? (ПРосто есть сотрудники,которые имеют несколько должностей и уволены только с одной, к сожалению, они тоже попадают в мою выборку, поэтому мой вариант не правильный).Как просто построить это логически?

Comment: Покажите, для начала, свой вариант и структуру базы, точнее ее часть, участвующую в запросе.

Comment: Будьте любезны, напишите полную структуру таблицы - какие в ней поля?

Answer (score 0):

Нужны ТОЛЬКО СОТРУДНИКИ? Ну тогда

```
SELECT employeeID -- или иное поле, уникально идентифицирующее человека
FROM employees
GROUP BY employeeID
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN dismissal_date IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1
```

Если надо больше (например, все записи таблицы для такого сотрудника) - используйте это как подзапрос в источнике данных для формирования условий отбора.